# If $H$ and $\frac GH$ are connected so is $G$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, topological-groups

In this [proposition](https://books.google.com/books?id=osXdDqP5qGcC&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=true):

[image]

Where in the proof is the closedness of the normal subgroup $H$ used?

Comment: Why did we assume $e \in A$? Where do we use this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not used or required.  But it's common to only talk about $G/H$ when $H$ is a closed subgroup, because otherwise $G/H$ will not be Hausdorff.  In particular, the book in which that proof appears defines topological groups to be Hausdorff (see page 84).