# Is there always a continuous surjection from $H \times G/H$ to $G$?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

Question:

> Is there always a continuous surjection $f: H \times G/H \rightarrow G$?

where $G$ is a topological group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G/H$ is given the quotient topology.

We know $H \times G/H$ is not necessarily homeomorphic to $G$, even in the case $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. (for example, take $G=\Bbb R$ and $H=\Bbb Z$). But that is evidently a stronger statement.

To find a counterexample, we may look for topological properties that are preserved by continuous maps. However, compactness and connectedness are already ruled out. For example, see [If $H$ and $G/H$ are compact, then $G$ is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322926/if-h-and-g-h-are-compact-then-g-is-compact) and [If $H$ and $\frac GH$ are connected so is $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616528/if-h-and-frac-gh-are-connected-so-is-g)

---

As commented by @MoisheKohan, it's not a very interesting question. What if I require $H$ to be closed?

Comment: No, this is false. Take G be the additive group of real numbers and H the subgroup of rational numbers.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh, that's so quick. Do you want to post it as an answer (or I could self-answer my question)?

Comment: @YuiToCheng you’d have to include an argument as to why no such surjection can exist.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, not very interesting. What if I restrict that $H$ to be closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with $H$ closed.

Take $G$ to be the product $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{Z}_p$ (here $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is in its usual meaning, i.e., the compact group of $p$-adic integers). Take $H$ to be the infinite cyclic subgroup generated by $(1,1)$.

*Claim:* $G/H$ is connected.

Granted the claim, let us conclude: given a continuous map $f:H\times G/H\to G$, every coset $\{h\}\times G/H$ being connected, it maps into a single connected component $\mathbf{R}\times\{x_h\}$ of $G$. Since $G$ has uncountably many connected components and $H$ is countable, we deduce that $f$ is not surjective.

To prove the claim, let $\pi:G\to G/H$ be the projection: it is enough to show that $\pi(\mathbf{R}\times\{0\})$ is dense. Indeed, since $\pi(n,n)=0$ for every $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, we have $\pi(\mathbf{R}\times\{0\})=\pi(\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{Z})$. Since $\mathbf{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbf{Z}_p$, the latter is clearly dense.

Answer (score 5):

An easy examples to the original question is: Take $G={\mathbb R}$ (the additive group) and $H={\mathbb Q}< G$. Then $H$ is dense in $G$, hence, every point is dense in $G/H$, hence, every continuous map $G/H\to G$ is constant. Thus, the image of every continuous map $F= H\times G/H\to G$ has (at most) countable image, hence, cannot be surjective.

As for the case when $H$ is closed, I do not know. It is not hard to see (using [Hahn-Mazurkevich theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39584/reference-for-a-proof-of-the-hahn-mazurkiewicz-theorem)) that for every Lie group $G$ and closed subgroup $H<G$, there is a continuous surjection $F\to G$. The same holds in the case when $G$ is metrizable, locally compact and totally disconnected. One should be able to prove the existence of a surjective continuous map when $G$ is a locally compact metrizable group (but I did not think about details).

One last thing: I find the question rather unnatural since it  essentially ignores the group structure of $G$.

Comment: With $H$ closed, take $G=\mathbf{R}$ and $H=\mathbf{Z}$. The only homomorphism from $G/H$ to $G$ is constant, because $G/H$ is compact and $G=\mathbf{R}$ has no nontrivial compact subgroup. Hence every continuous homomorphism from $H\times G/H$ to $G$ has a cyclic image.

Comment: @YCor: OP did not ask about homomorphisms only  continuous surjections.

Comment: Indeed. I actually realized this after writing my comment, and actually thought I had erased it. Then I posted an answer with an example not assuming group homomorphism.

Comment: @YCor: Oh, I see. Nice example!